# What is the word for "the space left behind when a shape is removed"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for "the space left when a shape is removed from something", like for example, the gingerbread-man shape left in the dough after the gingerbread-man has been cut out of it? Its not the "counterfoil", or "the negative"....I seem to remember there being a specific word for it, what is it?

Comment: maybe silhouette?

Comment: The technical term for that is a "hole"... (or maybe you need to be a bit clearer what you're looking for?)

Comment: Avoid word requests that lack: (i) objective criteria for accepting answers, including connotation, register, and part of speech; (ii) exact context – generally we want the sentence you’re writing; and (iii) details of research you’ve already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.) including solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. See: “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity – ELU Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”; “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Comment: Obligatory: Hole in the Wall gameshow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpRO2MlAYRk

Comment: Are memory lapses allowed?

Comment: When a word request attracts a long list of ideas, that is a clear signal that either the criteria are unclear or the question is more of a poll or request for a list of things, neither of which are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model.

Answer (score 19):

It's simply a **cutout**.

> Definition of *cutout*:
>
> 1: something cut out or off from something else; also: the space or
>   hole left after cutting

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cutout)

Disambiguation may well be necessary.

Comment: Interesting that the term refers to both the cutout and the cutout. :)

Answer (score 7):

You could say "the '**negative space**' left by the cookie cutter" -- this seems to be fairly common usage ([google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=negative%20space%2C%20cutout&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnegative%20space%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccutout%3B%2Cc0)) and is more specific than terms like "cutout" or "void".

A visual example of usage is here:  [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_space)

[image: rubin.jpg]

Comment: [Negative Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_space) is indeed an established term, but usually only among graphic designers and other visual artists.

Comment: +1 I actually just walked out of a meeting where someone (a psychologist, not an artist or graphic designer) used this term in reference to a photograph, so it may not be that specialized or obscure. (I don't know whether it would be my first thought for cookie cutter dough, though.) You might want to consider adding a definition, for clarity's sake.

Comment: I understand it as jargon from the visual arts, but it is important enough inside those fields to have come up in several introductory classes I've taken (both technique classes and appreciation classes), so I would guess that it is reasonably broadly understood.

Answer (score 6):

Void may work, albeit it is a bit more... poetic you may say.

> **Definition:**
>   *Noun:* A completely empty space.
>   *Adjective:* completely empty.

In your cookie example:

> The void left in the dough by my cookie cutter.

Answer (score 5):

If a shape is cut out, then what is left is a **shaped space**. The further description of the space depends on what was cut out :

> A **Mango Shaped Space**

[Porter Square Books](http://www.portersquarebooks.com/mango-shaped-space)

> Durrington Walls - an **oval shaped space**

[Antlantipedia](http://atlantipedia.ie/samples/archive-2140/)

> **Car shaped space**

[The Nature of the Mind](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=HT4SrefhZuIC&pg=PA95&lpg=PA95&dq=car+shaped+space&source=bl&ots=oThRJxVydF&sig=DzQCjt2IMTNHze35TEJbGOTOIw4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSkKuKo-_ZAhVCBMAKHfY9ADwQ6AEIZTAK#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> the three body cavities - a **horseshoe shaped space**

[Trilaminar Embryo](https://embryology.med.unsw.edu.au/embryology/index.php/BGDB_Gastrointestinal_-_Trilaminar_Embryo)

Note : Due to the relative obscurity of the wording, some of these references are buried in the links I have provided. I guarantee that they are there, but they require a little searching to pinpoint them.

Comment: Don't worry about phrases being buried on web pages. They can be located quite easily with <ctrl-F> searches (or equivalent) from the web browser. +1 for the answer.

Comment: @Lawrence Neat. I didn't know that was possible. Thank you.

Comment: I usually see phrases like this hyphenated, e.g. car-shaped space. Pretty much a matter of style, though.

Comment: @alex_d Yes, I was uncertain which to choose when I wrote them down.

Answer (score 4):

I think you may use [outline:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/outline)
​

> the main shape or edge of something, without any details.

Cambridge Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

[According to OLD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/imprint), **Imprint** is:

> A mark or outline made by pressing something on to a softer substance.

Example sentence (from the same link):

> ‘he made imprints of the keys in bars of soap’

In case of *imprint*, you should think of it like a stamp. If your gingerbread man uses some pattern that it *imprints* in the dough, this is the word your looking for. A similar example is a waffle iron, it presses a certain pattern on the food, that pattern may be called an *imprint*.

Answer (score 1):

[Form](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/form) (*noun*) The visible shape or configuration of something.

- Nelly cut out her gingerbread man from the dough, leaving a **form** shaped exactly like her cookie (which she thought was hilarious).

Comment: A form is an object, not the lack of one. In your answer, the gingerbread man is the form that was cut from the dough leaving the hole.

Comment: @Stan ~ A form can be an abstract noun, which isn't an object. "...the 'thing' might be an intangible concept – which means it is an **abstract form** of noun..." http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/nouns/abstract-nouns.html

Answer (score 1):

**Ghost** would also apply, particularly in this example.

Comment: And why would you think that ?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Could you explain why you believe the word is suitable? Perhaps you could cite a definition or usage example that suggests it fits the asker's needs.

Answer (score 1):

In paleontology this is called a "steincrone" or "steinkrone". Could not find a google link to this though. My spelling may be wrong as it is a German word. Sounds cool anyway.

Comment: Hard to believe this is widely known or accurate without a reference on the entire internet.

Comment: I was wrong. For a good time,  google("steinkern fossil"). This is a fossil formed by minerals that fill a mold left by another fossil and after the original mold disappears.

Comment: @ElmerT.Jones - If your answer's wrong, delete it.

Comment: OK, it's called a "mold" or "imprint".

Comment: Consider updating your answer to correct the spelling. A quick Google search reveals this word has been borrowed into English and even has a dictionary entry in English: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/steinkern

Answer (score 1):

While it might not be the specific word you are looking for, I liked Laurel's answer but it was only in the comments. I also liked Nigel's answer. For the widest understanding I would use "a gingerbread-man shaped hole was left behind in the dough"

Although I fear you want a single word, I would use cavity:

```
Definition of cavity    
plural cavities 

1 : an unfilled space within a mass; especially : a hollowed-out space
```

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cavity)

The gingerbread-man cavity

Answer (score -1):

How about **Trace**.

> a mark, object, or other indication of the existence or passing of something.

<sup>Source: [Google Dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b&q=Dictionary#dobs=Trace)</sup>